# what are the list of unsupported functions in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

In a recent Oracle upgradation from 11g to 12c, I found that `WM_CONCAT` was not supported in 12c and it has to replace with `LISTAGG`.

what are the other list of functions not supported in 12c.

what are the list of functions supported in 11g and and not supported in 12c.

I have tried to find out in oracle documentation but not getting the clear list.

Can some please help out with this information, thanks in advance.

Comment: WM_CONCAT has never been officially supported. It has never been officially documented on docs.oracle.com

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - this is a really important point. People find solutions like WM_CONCAT on sites such as SO and use them in their production code with noticing that the functions are undocumented and not supported. To be fair, it's often the case that the person who posted the solution was equally oblivious.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov, good point. Actually, Oracle documents why this function should not be used on any application:  WMSYS.WM_CONCAT Should Not Be Used For Customer Applications, It Is An Internal Function (Doc ID 1336219.1) https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=1alhngypen_4&_afrLoop=1485953003316449

Comment: I've been in this business almost 40 years now, and believe me when I say that the landscape is littered with code that was broken because it relied on undocumented functions/features/behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Deprecated and Desupported Features for Oracle Database 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm#UPGRD60000)
2. [Changes in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1, 12.1.0.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/release_changes.htm#ADFNS105)
3. [Changes in Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/release-changes.html#GUID-F9E8C757-75AB-4A9A-85AD-EC6383013FEB)
4. [Deprecated and Desupported Features for Oracle Database 18c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/rnrdm/deprecated-desupported-features.html#GUID-61D44BE2-21DE-463C-BEA9-8F8F1C75E45F)
5. [Behavior Changes, Deprecated and Desupported Features for Oracle Database (12, 18, 19)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/upgrd/behavior-changes-deprecated-desupport-oracle-database.html)